# How does Android differ from other Linuxes?

Tags: android, linux, architecture, internals

Could anyone suggest some detailed info about the internals of Android? I'm interested to know it's differences with other Linuxes, some detailed view of the Android architecture, etc. I've heard loads of scattered info, e.g. the *Surface Flinger*, the *Stage Fright* something, that it's got *Wake Locks*, etc., but I can't put that info together into something meaningful to me.

I just need to understand how Android works, but do it in detail. I'm not very much interested in the SDK or NDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android uses an optimized Linux-Kernel, but not 'glibc' for it's communication between the Kernel and the System. Instead, 'Bionic' is used.

The Apps for Android are written in Java, but not compiled to standard Java-Byte-Code. Also, they don't use a JVM from Oracle. The JVM used by Android is the 'Dalvik Virtual Machine', which reads Dalvik-Byte-Code. The DVM is bases on Apache Harmony, which is an OpenSource JVM implementation.

Also, if found an article on the same topic: [Link](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/News/How-Much-Linux-Is-in-Android)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I've heard most of that stuff. I'm rather looking for an organized in-depth tutorial.

Comment: It doesn't really 'differ' from other linuxes, it's a 90% custom solution on top of a linux kernel. Even the wake locks that you mention are a custom extension to the kernel and not available in the main line.